# Find all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $g(x) = 100|x+1| - \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x^k+1|$ is differentiable $\forall x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find all $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $$g(x) = 100|x+1| - \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x^k+1|$$ is differentiable $\forall x$.

It's my high school calculus problem. Is it possible to solve this problem in the high school curriculum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$g'(1^+)=100-1-2-3-\cdots$$
$$g'(1^-)=-100+1-2+3-\cdots$$

To be differentiable:
$$200=2+6+10+\cdots$$

Use the sum of an arithmetic progression formula.